# Wavelength Of Light

Tags: solar-system, solar-cells

How can we change different wavelengths/frequencys of Sunlight to produce single wavelength to achieve maximum efficiency of Solar Cells ?

Answer (score 5):

You change the wavelength of light through the nonlinear processes of [intermodulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodulation); some examples of these processes are [upconversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion), [downconversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion) and [multiphoton processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiphoton_fluorescence_microscope).

However, in the context of energy winning from solar radiation, the use of any such process to concentrate a spectrum into something more like a monochromatic source will *always* cost you more energy than you gain by increased efficiency and so forth. This is a simple consequence of the second law of thermodynamics applied to light, because what you are asking to do is to shrink the volume occupied by the input light in optical phase space and this cannot happen spontaneously.

Comment: +1, I might actually read the next question before I try to answer it.